# Different cut aria effect in aligning and comparing two STL file with cloudcompare

Tags: mathematical-statistics, image-processing, model-comparison

I have one project for dental thesis which some aspect of it is not clear for me.

In this project we need to compare one specific area of dental mold scan by cloudcompare software, so the area is only on teeth like the colored part shown below:

[image]

During the making the molds they have some problem with their molding materials like shortage of molding materials, so decide to mold only for some of teeth and omit the others, like the colored part of main model which shown below:

[image]

In this situation we have some complete mouth scan file (STL file) and for new part some incomplete molds scan, so i have tried to cut one of the previous complete molds like new area for second part of molds and done compare process,, one of important factor in this calculation is that when we cut the main file and align them together it must align two model differently, so if cutting have significant effect on results i think i must cut the previous models to reach the main area of new models also.

Now i don't know the error of cutting or not cutting in this calculation could be omitted, so asked here to understand based of statistical calculation could understand does i need to repeat the previous works and cut the old complete CAD files to same as new incomplete models, or not?

The results are like this:

[image]

more quality image could be seen [here](https://gofile.io/d/fFcn5k).

I have summarized the results in one **[pdf](https://gofile.io/d/ETnKsb)** .

CSV (excel) files for [complete model](https://gofile.io/d/LNBTd8) and [incomplete model](https://gofile.io/d/gVLoDu)